# How to correctly handle input argument of a python script when using parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I've the followint situation:

my script (say script.py) takes an argument as input. I have a .txt file with a sequence of possible inputs (each input is a string representing an ID).

within the script I do something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                  

import sys

def doStuff(ID):

        ID = str(ID)
        path = ID + "/posts?"

        print "\n\n\t"+path
        foo = ID + "hello"
        print foo
        print ID+"hello"
        sys.exit(0)

inputID =sys.argv[1]
print "Input ID\t-\t" + str(inputID)
doStuff(inputID)
```

if I run the code with

```
python script.py 123456789
```

I correctly get

```
        Input ID    -    123456789
        123456789/posts?
        123456789hello
        123456789hello
```

but if I do something like

```
cat IDs.txt | parallel python script.py {}
```

I get

```
Input ID    -    123456789
/posts? 123456789
hello6789
hello6789
```

what is happening here? when i concatenate strings the order is reverted, moreover in the last two prints the inputID is overwritten by "hello"

Comment: Look into the fileinput module, this helps you accept data from piped stdout lines: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html

Comment: It looks to be usefull if I should read the file inside the python script. In my case instead the input of the python script is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your .txt file has \r in it, because this does exactly what you see:

```
printf '123456789\r\n' | parallel python script.py
```

Remove the \r from the textfile or let GNU Parallel do it:

```
printf '123456789\r\n' | parallel python script.py '{= s/\r// =}'
```